# mysql/php update query parameter causing it to fail

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get my form to work the way [this video](http://youtu.be/Zr0ktM3fjaI?t=12m3s) works. (If you just move to the last 3-4 minutes you will see his final code.)

```
  $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE aznet_data_spare_inventory SET ID='$_POST[id]', Shelf='$_POST[shelf]', Device Type='$_POST[device type]' WHERE ID='$_POST[hidden]'";
```

If I take out the Device Type portion of my update query, the ID and Shelf updates will work, but when I try to make device type work it just breaks.  I guess I'm just wondering if there is rules against spaces or something along those lines.

Comment: Hello. Please tell us what you're doing and what is going wrong along with any error messages.

Comment: At a glance, you cannot have a column called Device Type. No spaces allowed. Try device_type.

Comment: The video doesn't seem to talk about it, but there are serious SQL injection vulnerabilities in the above code.

Comment: Jonathan, so in my Table Headers I would underscore all the Spaces ? And shredder when if I take the device type portion out of the query I can update the ID and shelf. but if I follow the same logic for device type it won't update anything. so logic told me that my query was breaking, but I wasn't sure if it was because of how my query is formatted or if the echo input was broken or a combination of both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all consider using MySQLi or PDO instead of MySQL, then try to debug your code

```
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE aznet_data_spare_inventory SET ID='$_POST[id]', Shelf='$_POST[shelf]', Device Type='$_POST[device type]' WHERE ID='$_POST[hidden]'";

if(mysql_query($UpdateQuery,$con)){
//query is ok
 echo "item is updated";
}else{
 die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: This is being hosted on a LAMP server, is MySQLi or PDO still an option ?

Comment: Yes, its an extension installed to php check this out http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: You guys are great, I will look up sqli and pdo... This is just for an internal webtool. This won't ever see the outside network, so I have time to learn proper standards. Again Thank you !!

Comment: you are welcome, just vote up for the answers and click on Accept answer so the thread is closed

Answer (score 0):

Note, MySql extension is deprecated and you should consider using MySqli or PDO. And you should never put user input data, e.g. `$_POST`, directly into your query. Research proper ways to sanitize that data.
I don't see you closing the `<tr>` tag in your while loop. Nor do you close any of your `<input>` tags.

and yes, MySql column names should not have any spaces either. Try renaming `Device Type` to `Device_Type`. If you checked if `mysql_query()` returned false and output `mysql_error()`, it would probably give some error details.